# Problems using Cloud IAP Special URLs after login in SPA

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I've been using Google Cloud IAP to protect my web apps under https://some-domain. However, I found a problem when accessing Cloud IAP special urls with nginx + static SPA. I found that if I wasn't logged in, I was able to access the special urls specified in: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/special-urls-howto. So, I have no trouble accessing endpoints like `https://some-domain/_gcp_iap/identity` and such if I wasn't logged in.

However, after I logged in, I wasn't able to access the special urls (`/_gcp_iap/*`) anymore and get redirected to the SPA error page instead. <strike>I noticed that I have this inside my nginx configuration:</strike>

```
location / {
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
}
```

Is this nginx config caused the problem? How do I resolve this?

Update: The root cause is due to service worker behaviour with 3xx redirects (usually happens during login/authentication). Is it possible to have service workers work together with IAP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps that must be done to get service workers work with GCP IAP.

1. Referring to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2237, I've solved this issue by adding the following script in my yarn build script:

   ```
   const fs = require('fs')
   fs.readFile('build/service-worker.js', 'utf8', (error, data) => {
       if (error) {
           return console.log(error)
       }

       const result = data.replace(/isPathWhitelisted\(\[[^\]]+/g, 'isPathWhitelisted(["^(?!\\\\/_).*"');
       fs.writeFile('build/service-worker.js', result, 'utf8', (error) => {
           if (error) {
               return console.log(error)
           }
       })
   })
   ```

   I am using `create-react-app` to build my app. Apparently, the service worker created by `create-react-app` by default bypasses the requests made to IAP. So, I replaced the existing path whitelisting pattern to a new one: `/^(?!\/_).*/` to prevent the service worker from bypassing requests to IAP because special urls in IAP are all prefixed by the underscore `_`.
2. Disable service-worker caching by modifying the Nginx configuration.

   ```
   location / {
   root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
       try_files   $uri /index.html;

       # disable service worker from being cached 
       location = /service-worker.js {
           expires off;
           add_header Cache-Control no-store;
           access_log off;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

We can actually use this option:

1. disable service worker if we don't really need a progressive web app
2. using a nginx configuration, in my case I'm using kubernetes to deploy my backend and front end, so `http://foo.bar will` represent my `foo deployment` located on `bar namespace`. The `$domain` variable will be substituted during deployment's runtime by using a substitution:

```
    server {
      listen 80;
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

      rewrite /_gcp_iap/[a-z_]*$ $domain permanent;

      location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
      }

      location /foo/bar {
        # Proxy pass for the backend service
        proxy_pass http://foo.bar;
      }
    }
```

To debug your service worker application you can actually use google chrome:

*chrome://inspect/#service-workers*